# Angularjs remove button not working

Tags: angularjs

i am building a shopping app. Somewhere in the app i need to show the user’s shopping cart and let him edit it.
I have **remove button** but **not working**...

[image]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app>
<head>
<title>Your Shopping Cart</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CartController">
<h1>Your Order</h1>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>{{item.title}}</span>
    <input ng-model="item.quantity" />
    <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
    <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
    <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
</div>


<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function CartController($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
            {title:'Srimad Bhagwat', quantity:8, price:3.95},
            {title:'rupa chintamani', quantity:17, price:12.95},
            {title:'ram charit manas', quantity:5, price:6.95}
        ];
    };

    $scope.remove = function (index) {
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working". Please provide details. What do you want that it does exactly?

Comment: on click of remove button.. those item should removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your $scope.remove inside the CartController's { }